# How to Click A Button Programmatically - Button in WebBrowser ( IE )

Tags: c#, html

I searched the internet and found examples for;

"How to click a button which is in a webBrowser(internet explorer) in C# ?"

And here is the code which is [working on google](http://www.farooqazam.net/c-sharp-auto-click-button-and-auto-fill-form/);

JS :

```
    void ClickButton(string attribute, string attName)
    {
        HtmlElementCollection col = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input");
        foreach (HtmlElement element in col)
        {
            if (element.GetAttribute(attribute).Equals(attName))
            {
                element.InvokeMember("click");   // Invoke the "Click" member of the button
            }
        }
    }
```

But my webpage button has different tags. So the program can't detect to click it.

My main question is; **How to click *this* button programmatically ?**

HTML :

```
<a class="orderContinue" href="Addresses" title="Sipar Ver">Sipar Devam</a>
```

Comment: What do you want clicking the link to achieve? To go to the address in the href?

Comment: Do you need this for testing? or this is part of your program? Also, what do you mean by "has different tags".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Naturally the code you've posted won't find the tag you've posted.  It's looking for tags of type `input`:

```
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input")
```

But as you say (and demonstrate):

> But my webpage button has different tags.

Thus, you need to look for the tag(s) that you use.  Something like this:

```
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("a")
```

This would return the anchor elements within the document.  Then, naturally, you need to find the specific one(s) you want to click.  That's what this line is doing:

```
if (element.GetAttribute(attribute).Equals(attName))
```

Whether it finds the target tag(s) depends entirely on the values for those variables, which I assume you know and can manage.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. But I don't understand it. webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("a") can collect all href-s. And then?

Comment: @LostInLib: And then what?  The code you posted is collecting the `input` elements in the document loaded into a `WebBrowser` object.  It then loops through them, looking for a specific attribute with a specific value (which may match zero or more elements) and invokes a click on matched elements.  All you need to do to switch from `input` elements to `a` elements is change the argument to the `GetElementsByTagName` method.  What more is needed?  In what way is it not working for you?

Answer (score -1):

Using jQuery, you could put a click event on that a tag.
You would want to place this code at the bottom of your page

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('.orderContinue').click(function() {
       alert('Sipar Ver has been clicked');
       // More jQuery code...
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: This code is not programmatically clicking a button, it adds an event handler instead. Also we cannot assume the page is under his control.