Load HTML content in WebView 2 (Windows Forms)
Im using WebView 2 to create a program, and I need to make it load a HTML code stored in the Resources of the Project (im using Visual Studio, .NET, Windows Forms and C#).
I tried with:
webBrowser.CoreWebView2.NavigateToString(Properties.Resources.index);
'index' is the file with the HTML code.
I appreciate any answer.

This question is similar to: How to read embedded resource text file. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

It's not clear what problem you're having (also not clear why this question has been promoted to the main site from the Staging Ground without the required details) -- Is the WebView Control initialized? If so, then post the initialization code. Or do you have an issue reading the resource file? If so, what this issue might be? Do you have some sort of exceptions? Post everything that's required to reproduce the issue, editing your question (i.e., not in comments), including the content of any exception, as text

The following may be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68592056/10024425
